# Installing particular version of Nginx using Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

My agenda is to write Ansible Playbook for installing nginx-1.8.1. But I couldn't install the specific version of Nginx using my below playbook. Getting error as "Failed to install some of the specified packages" [My Target OS is RHEL 8]

Could you please help me on the same. Kindly let me know if you need any other information.
Thanks in Advance.

---

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: To install Nginx
    yum:
      name: nginx-1.8.1
      state: present

  - name: To enable and start Nginx
    service:
      name: nginx-1.8.1
      state: started
      enabled: yes
```

Output:

```
TASK [To install Nginx] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failures": ["nginx-1.8.1 All matches were filtered out by modular filtering for argument: nginx-1.8.1"], "msg": "Failed to install some of the specified packages", "rc": 1, "results": []}
```

Comment: `My Target OS is RHEL 8` => did you install a specific yum/dnf repo for nginx to get older releases? Because I'm quite sure that the version you are looking for is not available in the default repos (as should be clearly reported by `dnf list --all nginx`)

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for your reply. 
I haven't downloaded any yum/dnf repo for nginx. Could you share me the cmd for downloading yum/dnf repo (to install nginx-1.8.1 (or) nginx-1.16.1)

Comment: I don't have any idea if one exists. I could google it but it will be faster if you do it yourself